# Given a (5,2) tensor, delete rows that have duplicates in the second column

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

So, let's assume I have a tensor like this:

```
[[0,18],
[1,19],
[2, 3],
[3,19],
[4, 18]]
```

I need to delete rows that contains duplicates in the second column only by using tensorflow. The final output should be this:

```
[[0,18],
[1,19],
[2, 3]]
```

Comment: Do you have code you tried ? Can you post ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to solve this with `tf.math.unsorted_segment_min` and `tf.gather`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[0,18],
                 [1,19],
                 [2, 3],
                 [3,19],
                 [4, 18]])


y, idx = tf.unique(x[:, 1])
indices = tf.math.unsorted_segment_min(tf.range(tf.shape(x)[0]), idx, tf.shape(y)[0])
result = tf.gather(x, indices)
print(result)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0 18]
 [ 1 19]
 [ 2  3]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)
```

Here is a simple explanation to what is happening after calling `tf.unique`:

[image]